# PDF file not getting deleted in iOS

Tags: ios6, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am creating PDF page by following link...

```
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/generating-pdf-documents/?search_index=3
```

I am not able to delete this PDF file using below method. I have commented error line...

```
self.fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[self.tablePdfListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

 if([self.fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:pdfPath] == YES)
 {

 [fileMgr removeFileAtPath: pdfPath error:nil];  //No visible @interface for NSFilemanager declares the selector removeFileAtPath 
 }
```

Could you please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find *removeFileAtPath:error:* method anywhere in the class reference of NSFileManager. It seems to be a very old instance method. There is a similar method *removeFileAtPath:handler:* that seems to be deprecated.

Try to use the *removeItemAtPath:error:* instead. From the [class reference of NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW18):

> **removeItemAtPath:error:**
>
> Removes the file or directory at the specified path.

You should be familiar with the usage. I would suggest you to assign the error param to NSError variable so that you can check the NSError at the end of the operation, just in case:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL deleted = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pdfPath error:&error];
if (!deleted) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to delete pdf at %@, reason: %@", path, error);
}
```

Comment: before inserting removeFileAtPath I had applied the same method as you have suggested. That time somehow removeItemAtPath was not working. I wonder how its working today. Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: NSLog is gives me this Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1f504530 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1f52efc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/8A4C9907-541C-4186-AE79-92772BEBCB16/Documents/so.pdf, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
)}. The file is getting remove.

Comment: @NavnathMemane so the file is removed but there is still error message?

Comment: Yes. by deleting tableview row array the pdf file is getting remove. And I can not access the PDF file by creating the same name(previously deleted) in the tableView array. Is it really getting remove? How can I cross check?

Comment: @NavnathMemane you need to check in your simulator path, as mentioned by the error message above.